# Updating the firmware of Arduino Mega2560

Tags: firmware, matlab

I wanted to connect my Arduino board to MATLAB although it recognized the Arduino board, I kept receiving the error that said:

"Internal error: The initialization of the server code is incorrect."

I got the recommendation of updating my Arduino board's firmware;
So I connected my board to my pc and opened Arduino IDE; It said that the Arduino Mega or Mega 2560 on com6 is connected.

I even uploaded the blink example to my board to make sure that it was connected and fully functioning. Which it was.

But in the above bar in Arduino IDE, "Tools" menu, when I select the "WIFI101/ Firmware Updater" It says that no supported board connected.
What should I do now?

*P.S:
I'm currently using Arduino IDE version 2.1.1 and MATLAB 2023a on Windows 11.*

I'm sorry, I'm really new to this and would appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have the WIFI101 shield on the Mega?  How are you wanting to use Wifi with the Mega?

Comment: I just want to update it's firmware
I don't know how...

Comment: The firmware you are trying to use is for the WiFi-101 shield.  It's not for an Arduino Mega.  The WiFi shield might go on a Mega, but this firmware does not.  Do you have that shield?  Or do you just have a Mega?

Comment: No I just have a Mega. As I have explained above, it gets detected in MATLAB but I can not fully connect it to MATLAB via its commands. So I got recommended to update my board. This is the link explained my MATLAB problem as well: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/contributors/29688717-ava/questions/?s_tid=ans_lp_my_ques

Comment: OK, I think I understand your confusion from the other thread.  The WiFi101 Firware updater is for updating firmware on a WiFi101 shield.  It has nothing to do with the Arduino Mega.  In order to communicate with matlab you will need some code running on the Mega.  You need to find that sketch and load it on the board.  That will load like a normal sketch.  It will not involve anything that actually says the word "firmware".

Comment: Start here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/setup-and-configuration.html
Then here.  This shows how to upload the firmware to the arduino: https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ug/configure-setup-for-arduino-hardware.html

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ug/configure-setup-for-arduino-hardware.html

This link has the instructions for connecting the Arduino board.  Look right at the first where it talks about the USB connection. Step 2 where you click program is the step where you are loading the server firmware onto the Mega.  That's the bit it sounds like you're missing.